In Rust, is there a trait implemented by any type T such that t.clone() yields a T?
Suppose that I am trying to make a function like:
func(iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>)
I think this works with func(vec), but not func(&vec), which is fine, but what if I want it to work with both?  Assume T implements Copy.  So I could write two versions of the function,
func_ref(iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = &T>) {
    let vec = iterator.into_iter().map(|t| *t).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    // Code using vec
}

func_val(iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = T>) {
    let vec = iterator.into_iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    // Code using vec
}

But then maybe I would also need a &mut T version as well, and it feels like it should be able to work for anything that implements Deref<Target = T>, but I think if I try to define my own trait that's implemented both for T and impl Deref<Target = T>, I'm going to run into the problem that theoretically T could implement Deref<Target = T> and so I can't have conflicting implementations...  So I just wonder if there's a solution to this.

Yes, Clone...

As commented by @cafce25, the answer to the title of your question is the Clone trait. From the body of your question, it looks like you are really looking for Borrow<T>, which is implemented for all T, &T and &mut T and allows you to get a &T, which you can then .clone() if T implements Clone. Your function would then look like:
pub fn func<T: Clone> (iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl Borrow<T>>) {
    let _vec = iterator.into_iter().map(|t| t.borrow().clone()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    // Code using vec
    todo!();
}

Playground

Unless you need the tight "Eq, Ord, Hash traits are equivalent" relationship Borrow gives most code could use AsRef as well which is more flexible.

@cafce25 Borrow<T> has a blanket implementation for T, AsRef<T> doesn't so AsRef wouldn't work with iterators that return owned Ts, e.g. the func_val of the OP's question.

The answer by @Jmb is correct, but it is not the most efficient if T has an expensive Clone, since it clones even when given owned Ts. It also needlessly constraint T: Clone when given owned Ts. You can solve that by using  a custom trait:
pub trait EfficientClone<T> {
    fn maybe_clone(self) -> T;
}

impl<T> EfficientClone<T> for T {
    fn maybe_clone(self) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl<T: Clone> EfficientClone<T> for &'_ T {
    fn maybe_clone(self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }
}
impl<T: Clone> EfficientClone<T> for &'_ mut T {
    fn maybe_clone(self) -> T {
        self.clone()
    }
}

pub fn func<T>(iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl EfficientClone<T>>) {
    let _vec = iterator
        .into_iter()
        .map(|t| t.maybe_clone())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    // Code using vec
    todo!();
}

fn main() {
    func([String::new()]);
    func::<String>(&[String::new()]);

    struct NonClone;
    func([NonClone]);
    // func::<NonClone>(&[NonClone]);
}

